# (HTML CSS) code example div is messing up my page

Tags: html, css

I created a div example, It uses /google/code-prettify library which is a color library.
It is basically a div inside another div with a textarea.
Whenever i try to add a new paragraph, header or another example in the next line, it messes up the page.
Something about the prettyprint lang class that is making it impossible to add more info down..

Can you see what i am missing?

### HTML

```
 <div class="examplebox">
            <h3>Code Example:</h3>
            <div class="exampleinsidebox">

                <pre style="padding-left:20px;"  class="prettyprint lang-python" >
                  <!-- !!!!! Start of showing Code !!!!!-->
                   # I am a comment
                  print("Free code wiki")
                <!-- !!!!! End of showing Code !!!!!-->
                </pre>
                </div>
                </div>

            <button
              onclick="window.location.href = '/TryYourselfCodes/pythonguide4.html'; "
              style="left:30px;"
              class="buttontest"
            >
              Try yourself >>
            </button>

          </div>
```

---

### CSS

```
.examplebox {
  background-color: #f3f4fa;
  border-style: unset;

  padding: 30px;
}
.examplebox h3 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.examplebox button {
  top: 20px;
}
.exampleinsidebox {
  background-color: black;
  border-style: unset;
}
.exampleinsidebox p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}



pre.prettyprint {
  padding: unset;
  border:none;
}

/*! Color themes for Google Code Prettify | MIT License | github.com/jmblog/color-themes-for-google-code-prettify */
.prettyprint {
  background: #343434;
  font-family: Menlo, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", Monaco,
    Consolas, monospace;
  border: 0 !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're closing `<div class="examplebox">` that div at `</pre></div></div>`
in the second closing div tag, and there is no opening `<div>` for - at the very last closing `</div>` tag. maybe that's causing problem.